# Getting the first century in a list of numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was sent this solution but Im having trouble understanding 
the `i >= len(line):` I'm a beginner programmer.

The code has to print out the first century which occurs in a list of numbers, and if theres no century then 'none' is printed. I'm not sure why he used the `i >= len(line)`

I personally wouldn't have thought of solving it this way so could someone explain what its doing?

this is the file i'm running the program against

```
1
12
99
101
65
110


import sys

lines = sys.stdin.read().split()

i = 0
while i < len(lines) and int(lines[i]) < 100:
    i = i + 1

if i >= len(lines):
    print 'none'
else:
    print lines[i]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service.  Maybe try out: http://www.pythontutor.com/ - unfortunately it doesn't support `import sys` - maybe refactor that part.

Comment: If the line counter (`i`) is greater than the number of lines (`len(lines)`) then no matching value was found. BTW, the solution won't work if you have a number like `007`.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a pythonic way to iterate over list via indexes, especially when it's not necessary at all. You can use [`for .. else`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement:

```
nums = [1, 12, 99, 101, 65, 110]
for i in nums:
    if i >= 100:
        print(i)
        break
else:
    print("none")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if i >= len(lines):  # if i > len(lines) you cannot print the lines[i] because that would be an out of range Exception that's why there is this condition to print None
    print 'none'
else:
    print lines[i]  # if i < len(lines) that means the call of lines[i] will give a value and thus printing it can occur successfully
```

I dont know why you are using this code because remmember in Python there is always an easier way. if your Code looks Complex and messy then there is something wrong if you are writing in Python. you can write it like this instead:

```
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Comment: ... Bear in mind that the if-statement is not inside of the loop itself.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have assigned the variable `line` to a list containing the integers in your input (i.e. 1, 12, 19, ..., 110). Calling the `len()` method on a list will return the number of items in that list. Specifically, using the `len()` method on your `lines` list will return the number of integers in your input (in your case 6).

The line `i >= len(lines)` will return whether you have iterated your variable `i` to an integer larger than the number of integer inputs. In other words, it will return whether you have gone through all of your input number checking if they are greater than 100. As you stated in your post, this program should return `"none"` if there are no "centuries" (weird phrasing btw). If your iterator `i` has exceeded the number of integer inputs, it means that none of your inputs were greater than 100, and your program should return `"none"`. However, I would like to point out that using `while` is less space-efficient that iterating through your `lines` variable item by item with `for`.